# How to search through global methods of managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, ide, class, search, global-methods

You can see global methods in the managed package classes via Web UI.  I have hundreds of managed package API classes that I need to search through by a keyword, to find a method that does what I need (or to know if there is even one like that).

Normally I run a full-text search of the Salesforce project in the IDE when I need to find something, but this does not work with managed classes, as their code in IDE is completely hidden, it's not even importing the global method definitions.

Any advice?  I really would rather not spend hours opening each API class manually in the web UI whenever I need to find something.

Comment: Not an answer per-se, but potentially useful: I see from your comment on a deleted answer this is about the c2g namespace prefix, better known as FinancialForce accounting. I'll note there's web-based API documentation at http://developer.financialforce.com/technical-reference/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just been playing with the tooling API and discovered that it would be possible  to retrieve the global method names for Apex classes within a managed package.

You could write a script that first queries all managed Apex classes (classes that have a namespace - there might be a better way to do this?):

```
https://SALESFORCE_DOMAIN_HERE/services/data/v28.0/tooling/query/q=SELECT+ID%2C+NamespacePrefix+FROM+ApexClass+WHERE+NamespacePrefix+%21%3D+null
```

And then retrieve the symbol table for each of these classes:

```
https://SALESFORCE_DOMAIN_HERE/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/CLASS_ID
```

Response will contain a symbol table with global method names/types, properties etc which should look something like:

```
...
"SymbolTable": {
    "constructors": [],
    "externalReferences": [],
    "innerClasses": [],
    "methods": [ 
        ...
    ],
    "namespace": "NS",
    "properties": [
        ...
    ]
```

You could parse this to output a nice list that could serve as the documentation you are after.

Sorry that I haven't pieced together all of the puzzle. If you think that you would like to continue down this path I can work with you towards a proper solution.

Comment: I was toying with this too. I'm probably going to make it into a VF page... It's too useful not to.

Comment: Yes, although it looks like one would need to do a separate callout for each ApexClass in order to retrieve all of the symbol tables. I wonder if there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: @sfdcfox You might be interested in the Apex Tooling API, this blog has an example of querying the Symbol table using SOQL, the example is for a specific class but can be used to return multiple. http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/03/17/going-native-with-the-apex-uml-tool-and-tooling-api/

Comment: @luke.mcfarlane You can actually retrieve the Symbol Table as part of your first query, just include it as a field in the select, thus you will get a list back of all symbol tables for selected classes, SELECT ID, SymbolTable, NamespacePrefix FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix ... Note that in the documentation it states that this results in a demand compile  if things are not in the salesforce cache for example, if you get a timeout you can try again or i typically just ensure the user does a Compile All Classes before trying again from the Apex Class page.

Comment: That's nifty. I can use that directly in the code I deleted, I suppose...